# Why is X undefined in this code?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define X (Y+4)
#define Y (X+3)
int main(void) {
    printf("%d\n",4*X+2);
    return 0;
}
```

Error: Undefined symbol 'X'.

Comment: What result did you expect?

Comment: Because there is no `Y` at the point of declaration. I was sure that C parses from top down.. That may be why but then again, I'm not sure if that is always the case.

Comment: The lesson here is just use the preprocessor to do simple stuff.

Comment: Run your code through a preprocessor and see if it resembles what you think it would (I imagine you want an endless loop of nested macros, since that is what you attempted to put in).

Comment: I know the code is absurd, but I came across it in a book of aptitude questions. Why not a 'Y' undefined and 'X' undefined?

Answer (score 5):

Macro expansion does not recursively re-expand the macro name.

Quoting the C standard:

> If the name of the macro being replaced is found during this scan of
>   the replacement list (not including the rest of the source file’s
>   preprocessing tokens), it is not replaced. Furthermore, if any nested
>   replacements encounter the name of the macro being replaced, it is not
>   replaced. These nonreplaced macro name preprocessing tokens are no
>   longer available for further replacement even if they are later
>   (re)examined in contexts in which that macro name preprocessing token
>   would otherwise have been replaced.

`X` expands to `(Y + 4)`. The preprocessor then attempts to expand `Y`, but since the expansion of `Y` refers to `X`, it doesn't expand it again, leaving the `X` in place.

This rule avoids infinite recursion in macro expansion (which is what you'd have in your example if this rule were not there).

After macro expansion, the line

```
printf("%d\n",4*X+2);
```

resolves to:

```
printf("%d\n",4*((X+3) +4)+2);
```

Since `X` has not been defined in a way that's visible outside the preprocessor, you have a compile-time error.

Answer (score 3):

Because X is defined by Y which also reuse X to define itself. Its a circular reference.

Comment: But there is no "circular reference" error as one would expect from a truly cyclic structure. Apply the logic, but look at the expansions per step.

Answer (score 2):

If you have gcc, use the `-E` switch and see the file after preprocessing:

```
>type example.c
//#include <stdio.h>
extern int printf(const char *s, ...);
#define X (Y+4)
#define Y (X+3)
int main(void) {
    printf("%d\n",4*X+2);
    return 0;
}
>gcc -Wall -E example.c
# 1 "example.c"
# 1 "<command-line>"
# 1 "example.c"

extern int printf(const char *s, ...);


int main(void) {
    printf("%d\n",4*((X+3)+4)+2); // see X?
    return 0;
}

>
```

Comment: This demonstrates how gcc's preprocessor expands it, but it doesn't explain why.

Answer (score 1):

The preprocessor macro `X` expands to `(Y+4)`. This contains another preprocessor macro `Y`, so it is expanded to `((X+3)+4)`. This in turns contains the preprocessor macro `X`.

There is a feature of the C preprocessor which blocks recursion: if the name of a macro appears during its expansion, it is left alone. This allows definitions like

```
#define f(x) (LOG("f called"), f(x))
```

(not very common, but possible). (If it wasn't for that feature, the preprocessor would loop forever in many cases such as this one, which wouldn't be useful.)

At this point, the preprocessor has finished its job, so `X` would need to be a variable name.
Which it isn't, hence the error message.

Comment: @user2864740 What do you mean by “not implementation”? This feature does require extra work in the preprocessor, to detect recursion.

Comment: Why does it require extra work if `f(x)` is not assigned (the result) until *after* `(LOG("f called"), f(x))` is expanded?

Comment: @user2864740 The expansion of a macro is resolved when the macro is encountered, not when it is defined.